# Is it possible to have a Gtk.Entry and a Gtk.Popover focused at the same time?

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk3

I am creating a history browser app that has a Gtk.Entry that allows users to manually enter a date into it, at the same time focusing the Entry opens a Gtk.Popover that contains a Gtk.Calendar within it. The problem is when the calendar is focused the entry loses focus and can no longer by typed in. Is it possible to have both the entry and the calendar focused at the same time?

Comment: as I know you can't focus two elements at the same time. Maybe you should move focus  back to `Entry` and eventually you can set "top-most" for Popover to keep it on top without focus. OR you should set focus on Calendar, get every key and send to Entry - but it can be difficult. Or maybe you should display Caledard in the same window as Entry. If you create minimal working code only with entry and popover then we can test some changes.